# AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_3'

Tags: python, ssl, tls1.3

I am trying to setup a tls context in python. I want to force TLSv1.3 usng:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_3)
```

This does not work as I receive the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_3'
```

I am on Ubuntu 20.04 and am using python version 3.8 and openssl version 1.1.1f.

Why doesn't it support TLSv1.3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TLS 1.3 protocol will be available with PROTOCOL_TLS in OpenSSL >= 1.1.1. There is no dedicated PROTOCOL constant for just TLS 1.3.

https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLContext

Footnote 3.

According to the protocol version description, this is how you set TLS 1.3 as the minimum version supported:

```
client_context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
client_context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
client_context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3
```

https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ssl.html#protocol-versions

https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/ssl.html#tls-1-3